# How to make three POST calls in one transaction?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, api

I have custom note creation API. They way models are designed

## First POST call

```
postURL = "http://localhost/api/v1/notes/"
addNote = {
    'title': noteTitle,
    'text' : noteText,
    'location' : noteLocation,
    'lock' : '0',
    'tags' : noteTags
}
```

This gives notesID.

## Second POST Call:

http://localhost/api/v1/notes/images/

- Uploads multiple images

## Third POST Call:

http://localhost/api/v1/notes/videos/

- Uploads multiple videos

## Here is my code:

```
def getAddNote():
    token=getToken()
    noteTitle=input("Enter Note Title: ")
    noteText=input("Enter Note Text: ")
    noteLocation=input("Enter Note Location: ")
    noteTagsInput=input("Enter Note Tags: ")

    tagList = noteTagsInput.split(",")
    print(tagList)
    tagList_=', '.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"', tagList))
    noteTags="["+tagList_+"]"


    postURL = "http://localhost/api/v1/notes/"
    addNote = {
        'title': noteTitle,
        'text' : noteText,
        'location' : noteLocation,
        'lock' : '0',
        'tags' : noteTags
    }

    print(addNote)
    postrequest = requests.post(postURL , headers={'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(token),'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(addNote))
```

Question: Is there a way to do 3 POST calls in one transaction?

I would like to submit images and videos one shot from my client application?

Comment: What do you mean by "one transaction"?  What's wrong with just doing three POSTs, one right after the other?

Comment: In my client application, moment user click on submit - I want note to be saved with images and videos thats what I meant by one transaction.

Comment: So... Just perform those 3 POST requests when user clicks a single button?

Comment: If you need it to be atomic then you'll need to redesign the API.

Comment: One option would be to create the post as a draft and add a third operation "publish" that transitions from draft to published post. This operation would only be possible after the other three operations completed successfully. Otherwise (alternatively) you could roll all operstions into a single request. I.E POST note + video + images together